# Invalid Session Token Parse Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

It was working fine until i deleted the app and run again in simulator. I'm using the 1.7.4 Parse SDk. I'm using the code

```
PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackgroundWithBlock { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

in my appdelegate after Parse setup.
I have no idea what this is happening, any fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not logged in, you need to log in.

If it won't work, try to reinstall the app.

Comment: yes ofcourse I'm logged in and the only solution is delete and reinstall which is quite not working for me. I want to test multiple accounts at same time.